# How do I make this JSON/AJAX code work in IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax

For some reason this isn't running in IE? Anyone know why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/", function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://sub.domain.com/u/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            i: e.ip
        },
        success: function (e) {
            window.location.replace("http://www.domain.com/")
        }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: @idor_brad [nope](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9)

Comment: "this isn't running" is a pretty detailed description of the issue. did it do the thing? and was the thing happening before the time, or after the time?

Comment: What version of IE? This sounds like a CORS issue. I'm guessing IE8 and 9 and that the AJAX is on a different domain, is that accurate?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I am not sure if it was running before. By "not running" I mean that it isn't redirecting and probably not capturing the JSON from that AJAX call either.

Comment: how about you try breaking it into steps, verifying each step is occurring, and then finding where the breakage lies. its called debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [CORs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) Issue, IE has limited CORS support.  If you are using IE 9 this should work if you add the following code above your code:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Anything below IE 9 will not work.  You could try using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) if a post is not a requirement.

Comment: I too think that's the issue. www.domain.com and sub.domain.com are two different domains for the browser

Comment: @ClydeLobo but the sub.domain.com is just a redirect... I wouldn't think that it would be a cross domain thing. No?

Comment: It doesn't matter the browser doesn't know it is a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the content type in the request. I hope IE will like this.

```
  contentType: 'application/json'
```

If it still doesn't work try to use the same domain then it might be the problem of Cross origin domain request.

Comment: No luck :-( The redirect doesn't go through unfortunately.